# How to display console.log to html with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am unable to show my input through html but it shows through `console.log()`. It is not showing up below on my list. My delete button also is not working as well. Not sure what is going on.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#addButton').click(function(){
    var task = $(".note").val();
    console.log(task);
    $(".todo-list").append('<li><div class ="button-center"><button id="delButton">Delete</button><button id="editButtton">Edit</button></div></li>');
  });
});

$('#delButton').click(function(){
  var deleteNote = $('ul').children().length;
  $('ul').children()[deleteNote - 1].remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header data-role="header"><h1>To Do List</h1>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </header>
        
  <div role="main" class="todo-container">
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text" class="note" placeholder="Input new note..">
        <button id="addButton">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>

<ul class="todo-list">
    <li>
        <div class ="button-center">
            <button id="delButton">Delete</button>
            <button id="editButtton">Edit</button>    
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the solution below, the task content is dynamically inserted into the HTML code; the easiest way to do this is to use `${variable}`. Improved the click event to delete the related `<li>` element when the delete `<button>` is clicked.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#addButton').click(function() {
    var task = $(".note").val();
    
    /* New <li> should not be added when task is not entered. */
    if(task.length == 0) {
      alert("Please enter a task.");
      return;
    }
    
    /* Task content is added to dynamic content. */
    $(".todo-list").append(`<li><span>Task: ${task}</span><div class="button-center"><button class="deleteButton">Delete</button><button class="editButtton">Edit</button></div></li>`);
    
    /* After clicking the Add button, the <input> element is cleared. */
    $(".note").val("");
  });

  /* Fires when clicking the <button> element with the ".deleteButton" class style applied. */
  $(document).on('click', '.deleteButton', function () {
      /* The two parents of the <button> element are the <li> element. */
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  user-select: none;
}
ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}
button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery Reference -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div role="main" class="todo-container">
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text" class="note" placeholder="Input new note..">
    <button id="addButton">Add</button>
  </div>

  <ul class="todo-list"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @user18131775 I found a bug and fixed it. If the user clicks the Add button without entering any task, a `<li>` with empty content is added. Since this is undesirable, I blocked this behavior.